# How do I make Chef wait for the app deployment before moving files?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have the following Chef recipe

```ruby
aws_s3_file "/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/system.war" do
  bucket "mybucket"
  remote_path "builds/system_latest.war"
  aws_access_key_id node[:aws_access_key_id]
  aws_secret_access_key node[:aws_secret_access_key]
end

service "tomcat" do
  action [:restart]
end

aws_s3_file "/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/system/WEB-INF/application.properties" do
  bucket "mybucket"
  remote_path "config/application.properties"
  aws_access_key_id node[:aws_access_key_id]
  aws_secret_access_key node[:aws_secret_access_key]
end
```

It works fine every time I run it, except if the machine is a fresh one.

When it is a fresh machine, I get:

> Errno::ENOENT
>   ------------- No such file or directory - /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/system/WEB-INF/application.properties

I think that it happens because tomcat is not done deploying the application, so the folder does not exist when this statement is run.

I imagine that moving files around when an application is deployed is a normal procedure. How can I do that and guarantee that Chef is going to wait until the deploy is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write some code (probably in either Ruby or Bash) to query if Tomcat is done, when put it in a while loop.

```
ruby_block 'wait for tomcat' do
  block do
    true until ::File.exists?('/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/system/WEB-INF')
  end
end
```

Comment: That will result in a resource that will be "updated" every chef run, right?  Probably an unfortunate but necessary evil.  Just a thought, but what would you think about putting this sort of loop into an `only_if` or `not_if` for an existing resource?  Would that work?  And wouldn't that still cause the chef run to wait, but without the side effect of an "updated" resource?

Comment: If you are the kind of person that cares about resource update counts (hint: don't) you could use an LWRP instead.

Comment: But I do want to replace the file even if this exists. This is the file where the developers set the properties for the application, so it should be updated on every deploy :)

Comment: How can I add a `timeout` to this? If file doesnt arrive after (say) 30 seconds then something is wrong and I want my recipe to fail.